# How to deep copy a matrix in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures, deep-copy

I got a `List<List<CustomClass>>`, where `CustomClass` is a reference type.

I need to make a full deep copy of this matrix into a new one. Since I want a deep copy, each CustomClass object in the matrix has to be copied into the new matrix.

How would you do that in an efficient way?

Comment: is your CustomClass already implementing ICloneable or does it have a .Clone method already?

Comment: Assuming the `CustomClass` is marked `ISerializable` you can get a deep clone with very little code by serializing the object and deserializing it.  Not sure it meets your "efficient" marker though, so I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: @Davide Piras: CustomClass is not implementing ICloneable yet, but implementing it wouldn't be a problem. Therefore, I'll accept solutions which use ICloneable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a CustomClass that implements ICloneable, this isn't very difficult:

```
var myList = new List<List<CustomClass>>();

//populate myList

var clonedList = new List<List<CustomClass>>();

//here's the beef
foreach(var sublist in myList)
{
   var newSubList = new List<CustomClass>();
   clonedList.Add(newSubList);
   foreach(var item in sublist)
      newSublist.Add((CustomClass)(item.Clone()));
}
```

You can make this work in a similar way with any "DeepCopy"-type method, if you feel you don't want to implement ICloneable (I would recommend using the built-in interface though).

Comment: Aren't you missing a cast in the line newSublist.Add(item.Clone()) ?

Answer (score 2):

One easier way to **serialize** the whole object and then **deserialize** it again, try this extension method:

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source)
{
  if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
  }

  // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
  {
    return default(T);
  }

  IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
  using (stream)
  {
    formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
  }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
List<List<CustomClass>> foobar = GetListOfListOfCustomClass();

List<List<CustomClass>> deepClonedObject = foobar.DeepClone();
```

Comment: Why the double List<List< in DeepClone?

Comment: That's what mentioned in question. Isn't it?

Comment: You should be able to specify T as the type of the "this" parameter, and then the method will be able to infer the generic type based on the passed variable, making the usage simpler.

Comment: @KeithS Thanks, that would make specifying  type optional :) Updating code now

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Implement the ICloneable interface on your CustomClass, then you can clone your objects.
2. If the class can be serialized, serialize it to a memory stream and deserialize it from there. That will create a copy of it.

I would prefer to take the first alternative, because I think serializing / deserializing is slower than cloning via ICloneable.

Comment: Serializing to a MemoryStream and back actually isn't too bad. Cloning field-for-field to a new object would still be faster, but you have maintainability issues; each new field has to be represented in the Clone() method. XML serialization in a case like this wouldn't need to be touched when making any of a wide variety of possible future changes. So, I would recommend implementing ICloneable with some form of in-memory serialization.

Comment: @KeithS: You're right, the last sentence was just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Copy` method which can duplicate `CustomClass` objects:

```
var newMatrix = oldMatrix
    .Select(subList => subList.Select(custom => Copy(custom)).ToList())
    .ToList();
```